# get hidden field value in JavaScript / jQuery from updatepanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am sure this must have been covered but I can't find the anwser. I have an `asp:hidden` field in an `asp:update` panel that I need to get the value of in a JavaScript/jQuery. I can't seem to get it the normal way, `document.getElementById('<% =controlid.ClientID %>').value;`

It must be something to do with ajax or something but I can't figure it out.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Do you output a field whose ID is equal to the client's ID, and you're looking for the value of that field?   (EG:  Does your output form have `<input type="hidden" id="`TheClient's ID goes here `" val="??"/>` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jQuery : (updatepanel or not).

```
$('#<%= controlid.ClientID %>').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing, it sounds like you and ASP are server-side coding the output Javascript, right?  (I have JS experience, but little ASP, so bear with me for guessing with only a few tutorials on `UpdatePanel`s ...)

Based on that note, here's what I think you're seeing:

1. Your ASP.net writes out the ID of the ClientID field into the Javascript you wrote.  (If you're lucky)
2. Your Javascript looks for the field matching the client's ID number, **but not the actual client ID *field***.

So, instead of your output Javascript being, "document.getElementById('ClientID').value" *which it may need to be on the client side*, your output Javascript is, "document.getElementByID('234234234').value".

I've added a comment to your question above that basically asks, "Do you output a field whose ID is equal to the client's ID, and you're looking for the value of that field?"

Answer (score 0):

Try Something different today:

```
$("input[id$=hfContainerHeight]").val()

<input id="hfContainerHeight" type="hidden" value="100" runat="server" />
```

+1 For Royi answer...